# Что можно сделать на Python?

Tags: python, проекты

Подскажите что необычное можно сделать на питоне?
Всякие "калькуляторы" не предлагать)) 
Я уже написал несколько "учебных проектов" и реализовал пару своих идей.
Хотелось бы сделать что-то не очень боянистое и желательно трудное.

Comment: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts.

Answer (score 2):

Коллективный блог напишите. Чтобы была возможность зарегистрироваться, авторизоваться, заполнить о себе информацию, загрузить аватарку, написать, отредактировать и удалить пост, читать ленту постов, комментировать посты, оставлять голос за посты или комментарии, посмотреть чужой профиль и т.д. и т.п.